# c# printing ID, name and birthdate from sql table using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to print the Id, name and birthdate of entities from "Clients" table in sql using entity framework 6. so far i managed to print out one coloumn at a time but now combining Int with String and DateTime gives me an error: "Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'.

this is my code which i was trying to combine those types. am i missing a method of combining those type together unlike SQL?

```
var clientsList = (from c in context.Clients
                               orderby c.birthdate ascending
                               select c.ID && c.name && c.birthdate);

            foreach (var c in clientsList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
```

Comment: `select new { c.ID, c.name, c.birthdate };`

Comment: @Gusman Simple yet elegant. Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also

```
var clientsList = (from c in context.Clients
                   orderby c.birthdate ascending);

foreach (var c in clientsList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ClientID:{0}, ClientName:{1}, ClientBirthDate:{2}",c.ID,c.name,c.birthdate));
}
```

Comment: Oh that's right, i do familiar with this method. I even used something similar to that in another program i was studying: 'foreach (var c in smallestClientsID)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{c.ID} {c.name}");
                }'

Comment: yes that syntax is the newer string interpolation in C# 6.0